# Dynamic Textfields using jquery and calculating field value

Tags: jquery

I am working on jquery code to add dynamic fields to the list of my fields, i have couple of web links but most of them using using live command does not work as expected, all i am doing this inside the jquery UI Tabs

I gave a try with this code, as it works well but has couple of issues:

```
function trimNums(stringToTrim)
        {
            return stringToTrim.replace(/\d+$/,"");
        }         
        function dupForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
        {
        //alert(divId+'   '+divClass);
            var num     = $(divClass).length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
            var i;

            var newElem = $('#' + divId + num).clone().attr('id', divId + newNum);

            for (i=0; i < newElem.children().length; i++)
            {
                var attrId = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id'));
                var attrName = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('name'));

                newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id', attrId + newNum).attr('name', attrName + newNum);
            }
            $('#' + divId + num).after(newElem);
            $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled',false);

            //if (newNum == 15)
                //$('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','disabled');
        }

        function rmForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
        {
            var num = $(divClass).length;

            $('#' + divId + num).remove();
            //$('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','');

            if (num-1 == 1) {
                $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled',false); 
            }
        }
<div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn" onclick="dupForm('input', '.clonedInput', 'btnAdd', 'btnDel');" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" class="btn" onclick="rmForm('input', '.clonedInput', 'btnAdd', 'btnDel');" value="Remove" /><br /><br />
    </div>
            <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level-inputfields" name="product1" id="product1" placeholder="Product Details" />
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level-inputfields" name="price1" id="price1" style="width:50px;" placeholder="Price" />
            </div>
```

Issues with the Code:

1. It is also clones the value if i enter the value in one field and click on add which i do not want.
2. in the Price field, i want to enter the price value and it should get calculated immediately in the div box, i will define later. if i click remove the amount should be deducted immediately

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) After cloning, set value to empty:

```
var newElem = $('#' + divId + num).clone().attr('id', divId + newNum).val('');
```

or

```
var newElem = $('#' + divId + num).clone().attr('id', divId + newNum);
newElem.val('').attr('value', '');
```

However, cloning should NOT copy the value, as stated in the jQuery API:

> > the dynamic state of form elements (e.g., user data typed into input, and textarea or user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements.

As for (2), you did not provide sufficient info. Please post your code which sums up the price fields, and the "div" box HTML.

If you do not have it yet, firstly, add a div box with an ID like this:

```
<div id="answer">0</div>
```

Next, add this JavaScript code:

```
function recalculateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[placeholder=price]').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    };
    $('#answer').text(total);
}
$(function() {
    $('body').on('keyup', 'input[placeholder=price]', recalculateTotal);
});
```

And add this to the last line of your function `rmForm`:

```
recalculateTotal();
```

Comment: +1 for giving an option to add the .val(), but that did not worked, The field calculation is based on the following: `$('#answer').text(newElem); <tr>
          <td><label for="total"><strong>Total</strong></label><span id="answer"></span></td>
        </tr>`

Comment: the line `$('#answer').text(newElem);`  is already added above in the main code

Comment: It does not seems to be working, i am using this inside the jquery UI tabs, but i pulled out the page and tried on single, still it is not going inside the lop and nothing is being calculated

Comment: I am not getting any error, but i worked on the dupForm function and added the line you provided above for cloning, but it is still copying the values to next set of textboxes when i click the add button

Comment: for the value being cloned, figured out another way. Here it works like this `newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id', attrId + newNum).attr('name', attrName + newNum).attr('value','');`

Comment: unfortunately, i do not have live link here is the generated link in the jsfiddle

Comment: Here is my Complete Code and the Things which are not working Properly

1. Fields is being calculated only on the first price textfields, if i enter value in additional fields, they are not reflected in the answer or the amount section.

2. VAT is showing sometime NaN and it does not work anymore after showing NaN.

Please guide me with update in the following script in which i am lacking,                                                                           jsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sgeuH/